Placement/Installation of Huge Umbrellas in Arafaat ground , permissible or not?
This questions is to those respectable scholars who are specialized in fiqh especially Hajj related matters
I know that staying in Arafaat is manadatory part of Hajj but what about shari ruling regarding shading types facilities there especially in summer Hajj?
What if that whole area is covered is Huge Umbrellas that are are also there in Medina Mosque,is this allowed or will it invalidate Hajj?

This site is not a fatwa site and none of us are qualified scholars who are able to give you our own opinions. This site's answers are only supposed to refer to other academic sources of Islam and scholarly opinions. Please refer your question to islamqa.info, seekersguidance.org, or a similar site and read https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more info.
